# UIStackView not appearing in Container View

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview

Can someone please explain to me why I cannot see this StackView show up in its container?

This is what it looks like now:
[image]

This is what I want it to look like, ignore the cells, I just need to figure out why the Edit button, search bar and Sort button are not showing.
[image]

Here is the code I used to setup the views and their contents:

```
    // Container
    let barViewFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, view.frame.width, 44)
    let barViewContainer = UIView(frame: barViewFrame)
    barViewContainer.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 231/255, green: 231/255, blue: 231/255, alpha: 1.0)
    tableView.tableHeaderView = barViewContainer

    // Edit Button
    let editButton = UIButton(type: .System)
    editButton.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44)
    editButton.setTitle("Edit", forState: .Normal)

    // Search Bar
    let searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 44))
    searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
    searchBar.searchBarStyle = .Prominent
    searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 231/255, green: 231/255, blue: 231/255, alpha: 1.0)

    // Sort Button
    let sortButtton = UIButton(type: .Custom)
    sortButtton.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44)
    sortButtton.setImage(UIImage(named: "Sort"), forState: .Normal)

    // Stackview
    let stackViewH = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [editButton, searchBar, sortButtton])
    stackViewH.axis = .Horizontal
    stackViewH.alignment = .Center
    stackViewH.spacing = 8

    barViewContainer.addSubview(stackViewH)

    barViewContainer.addConstraints([
        stackViewH.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(barViewContainer.leftAnchor),
        stackViewH.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(barViewContainer.topAnchor),
        stackViewH.rightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(barViewContainer.rightAnchor),
        stackViewH.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(barViewContainer.bottomAnchor)])
```

Comment: Try adding `stackViewH.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`

Comment: Perfect that worked. Thank you! Even after reading  'translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints' description from the docs I'm still not sire what it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you add views programmatically, iOS assumes that you want to layout those views using frames. To make this work with auto layout, behinds the scenes it adds constraints so the view will appear according to its frame. But, you are adding constraints that you want the auto layout engine to use rather than the ones it would like to create. So to tell auto layout not to generate those constraints you can set the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false` for the views on which you don't want this to occur.

In your case:

```
stackViewH.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up for me. I understand what I was doing wrong.